# php, html and pdf with drupal

Tags: php, pdf, drupal

Having the next PHP code that produce HTML code:
(simplified function, the real one on same idea but longer with loops and so on):

```
<?php
function show_doc_html() {
    $text_to_title = "some text from db";
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                <?php echo $text_to_title ?>
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
    <?
}
```

I would like to return a PDF to the user, without changing too much of this  code.  we are working under drupal so we have function that can get html string and convert it to pdf, but the former function doesn't return anything but printing to stdout.  Id it possible?  or should i rebuild the old function to return string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way was to encapsulate my function with "ob_start()" get all text using "ob_get_contents()", then convert it to pdf.
Something like:

```
function show_doc_pdf()  {
    ob_start();
    function show_doc_html() ;
    $html_var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    //use wkhtmltopdf api on $html_var to return pdf
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [that](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf) what you need?
I have used it in my project. You can just write your markup and inline css in node template using view_mode = 'PDF'

Comment: tnx, I'll test it tomorrow.